# Is there any advantage to using the associated type compared to the concrete implementation type?

Tags: rust

Is there any advantage to using `Self::Output` over `Int256` as the return type in this code?

```
impl Add for Int256 {
    type Output = Int256;

    fn add(self, v: Int256) -> Self::Output {
        // ...
    }
}

impl Add for Int256 {
    type Output = Int256;

    fn add(self, v: Int256) -> Int256 {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really, it's purely stylistic.  Maybe it communicates the intent better, or you have to do less typing when copying the function signature from the trait defintion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two signatures from the compiler's perspective, so the decision is going to be all about which is better suited for humans reading and understanding the code.

I typically prefer to use the **associated type** rather than the concrete type.

This comes up in implementations of the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait. Suppose we have a type that exposes an iterator over booleans.

```
impl Iterator for MyBits {
    type Item = bool;

    fn next(&mut self) -> ??? {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

For the `???` we can put either `Option<Self::Item>` or `Option<bool>`. Someone quickly skimming this code will have an easier time reading `Option<Self::Item>` because it better captures the meaning of the return type -- the next item in the iteration, if there is one. If we were to write `Option<bool>` then the meaning is less self-evident -- maybe the bool somehow indicates whether there are remaining items...?